# subqueries in impala case statements

Tags: subquery, case, impala, statements

```
select
a.time, b.name, c.user_city, 
case
    when c.user_country='xxxx' and c.user_state in (select cast(state_id as string) from states_list)
    then (select d.STATE_NAME from States_LIST d where d.STATE_ID = cast(c.user_state as int) )
    else c.user_state 
end state,
case
    when c.user_country in (select cast(COUNTRY_ID as string) from COUNTRIES_LIST) 
    then (select e.COUNTRY_NAME from COUNTRIES_LIST e where e.COUNTRY_ID = cast(c.user_country as int)) 
    else null
end country, col6, col7, ......
from ......
where.......
```

while executing the above query in Impala I am getting the error mentioned below:

> incompatible return types Array and string of exprs 'select
>   d.STATE_NAME from States_LIST d where d.STATE_ID = cast(c.user_state
>   as int) ' and 'c.user_state'

please help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

As the error message shows you are trying to assign both a string and an array in the same case. The case statement can thus only work if the subquery will have only a single output.

What you would need for this purpose is a scalar subquery. Depending on the problem you need to solve you could try with an aggregation function.

From Impala documentation:

> A scalar subquery produces a result set with a single row containing a
>   single column, typically produced by an aggregation function such as
>   MAX() or SUM()

The second reason why this won't work is because **Impala does not allow subqueries in the select clause**.

> A subquery can return a result set for use in the FROM or WITH clauses, or with operators such as IN or EXISTS.

Depending on your tables you will have to solve this by joining with the `d` and `e` tables so the need for a subquery dissapears.
Example:

```
select
a.time, b.name, new.user_city, 
case
    when new.user_country='xxxx' and new.user_state is not null
    then new.STATE_NAME
    else new.user_state 
end state,
e.country_name country,
col6, col7, ......
from
a,
b,
countries_list e right outer join
        (select * from
            (select * from states_list) as d
             right outer join c on cast(d.state_id as string)=c.user_state
         ) as new
on e.COUNTRY_ID = cast(new.user_country as int)
,..
where
...
```

Please let me know whether one of these solved your issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did try joining the states table but still it did not work. All I need is, users selects the state in drop down list which will be saved as state code in string format, I need to check whether the user entered state is in my states table list if yes pull the state name, if user state input is not a valid value then it should take the input directly whatever user enters. This is the requirement, please let me know how this can be achieved in impala...........

Comment: Added an example of how a join could help you. Haven't tested it yet, so it could contain minor bugs and optimization possibilities

Comment: yes I have tried adding LIMIT 1, it says 'subqueries not supported in the select list'

Comment: And what about the join I proposed?

Comment: I tried the join you proposed, now I am getting the state name, but country name and user details are getting duplicated, I mean it is repeating the same user record with different state names and same country name:-( please help

Comment: It looks like the join condition on the state is not narrow enough. This means it is not joining 1 on 1 but rather 1 on many rows. I am checking my code, please provide any useful input you can think of :)

Comment: this happens when we join the user_personal_details with states list and countries list

Comment: Am I then incorrect in assuming that one `user_state` would map to exactly one `state_id` and  one `user_country `maps to one `country_id`?

Comment: To check what is happening can you place the four fields mentioned above in the select statement as well?

Comment: my query goes like this:

Comment: select sm.time, b.user_name, p.user_city,
case 
 when p.user_country = '1001' and p.user_state in (select cast(STATE_ID as string) from STATES_LIST) then (select sl.state_name from states_list sl where sl.state_id = cast(p.user_state as int)) else p.user_state end state,
case 
 when p.user_country in (select cast(COUNTRY_ID as string) from COUNTRIES_LIST) then (select cl.COUNTRY_NAME from COUNTRIES_LIST cl where cl.COUNTRY_ID = cast(p.user_country as int)) else null end country, ........other columns..... from ....tables list....,USER_PERSONAL_DETAILS p, where .......

Comment: that was my initial query which was not getting executed stating subqueries not supported

Comment: as you see in the case statement, when p.user_country='1001' and p.user_state is in the states_list then pick the statename from states_list using state_id else print p.user_state as it is. The same case for p.user_country also, if p.user_country is in the countries_list then pick country_name using country_id else print country as 'null'

Comment: Yeah sure I get your query :). But this is exactly what my join tries to achieve. It just joins the country and state table with the user table and if a state for example does not appear it will be NULL because of the right join. What I see from your results is that the joins do not have the effect I would expect. Normally I would expect that every user country and state would map to exactly one country or state. But it seems like this is not the case. That's why you should add all fields in the ON clause to the select and tell me what the output is if you execute my query.

Comment: I tried ur join as below:
select sm.time, b.user_name, p.user_city, case when new.user_country = '1001' and new.user_state is not null then new.state_name else new.user_state end state, case when new.user_country is not null then new.user_country else null end country,, ........other columns..... from ....tables list....,USER_PERSONAL_DETAILS p, countries_list cl right outer join (select * from (select * from states_list) as sl right outer join user_personal_details p on cast(sl.state_id as string)=p.user_state) as new on cl.country_id=cast(new.user_country as int)  where .......

Comment: and I got the output as I said earlier "repeating the same user record with different state names and same country name"
please let me know all fields from which table I should add and where should I add, is it after 'as new on'

Comment: `select 
sm.time, b.user_name, p.user_city, c1.country_id,new.user_country,new.state_id,new.user_state,
case ...` So add a few fields in the select.